# Google Contact API Error: Request via script load timed out. Possible causes: feed URL is incorrect; feed requires authentication

Tags: javascript, api, contacts, google-api

Hi I have an Error on Google Contact JavaScript API. The code was working fine from last day. But its not working today. Don't know what went wrong. :(

```
Request via script load timed out. Possible causes: feed URL is incorrect; 
feed requires authentication.


<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("gdata", "1.x");</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    google.setOnLoadCallback(initFunc);

    var contactsService;

    function setupContactsService() {
      contactsService = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactsService('GoogleInc-jsguide-1.0');
    }

    function logMeIn() {
      var scope = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds';
      var token = google.accounts.user.login(scope);
    }

    function initFunc() {
      //logMeOut();
      setupContactsService();
      logMeIn();
      getMyContacts();
    }

    function getMyContacts() {
          var contactsFeedUri = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full';

          var query = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactQuery(contactsFeedUri);

          // Set the maximum of the result set to be 5
          query.setMaxResults(10000);

          contactsService.getContactFeed(query, handleContactsFeed, handleError);
    }

    var handleContactsFeed = function(result) {
    var entries = result.feed.entry;
      for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        var contactEntry = entries[i];
        var emailAddresses = contactEntry.getEmailAddresses();

        for (var j = 0; j < emailAddresses.length; j++) {
          var emailAddress = emailAddresses[j].getAddress();
        }    
      }
    }

    function handleError(e) {
          alert("There was an error!" + (e.cause ? e.cause.statusText : e.message));
          //alert(e.cause ? e.cause.statusText : e.message);
    }

    function logMeOut() {
        google.accounts.user.logout();
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<IMG SRC="image.jpg"/> <!-- // Image for authentication -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me. Tested in Chrome, Safari, and FireFox. Summary of changes:

- Check if logged in already, if so, don't attempt to log in again.
- Removed `google.setOnLoadCallback(initFunc);` and replaced with a button click event. initFunc should never be called on page load.
- **IMPORTANT**: If there is not an image on the page that is loaded from the same domain as your page, this will not work (per google).

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("gdata", "1.x");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var contactsService;
        var scope = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds';

        function setupContactsService()
        {
            contactsService = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactsService('GoogleInc-jsguide-1.0');
        }

        function logMeIn()
        {
            var token = google.accounts.user.login(scope);
        }

        function initFunc()
        {
            setupContactsService();

            if (google.accounts.user.checkLogin(scope))
            {
                getMyContacts();
            }
            else
            {
                logMeIn();
            }
        }

        function getMyContacts()
        {
            var contactsFeedUri = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full';
            var query = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactQuery(contactsFeedUri);

            // Set the maximum of the result set to be 5
            query.setMaxResults(1);

            contactsService.getContactFeed(query, handleContactsFeed, handleError);
        }

        var handleContactsFeed = function (result)
        {
            var entries = result.feed.entry;
            for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)
            {
                var contactEntry = entries[i];
                var emailAddresses = contactEntry.getEmailAddresses();

                for (var j = 0; j < emailAddresses.length; j++)
                {
                    var emailAddress = emailAddresses[j].getAddress();
                    alert(emailAddress);
                }
            }
        }

        function handleError(e)
        {
            alert("There was an error!" + (e.cause ? e.cause.statusText : e.message));
        }

        function logMeOut()
        {
            google.accounts.user.logout();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="initFunc();" value="Test" />
    <img src="image.jpg" />
    <!-- // Image for authentication -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (google.accounts.user.checkLogin(scope))
        {
            setupContactsService();
            getMyContacts();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**EDIT**

Added the following code right before the `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (google.accounts.user.checkLogin(scope))
    {
        setupContactsService();
        getMyContacts();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: James, this is the worst possible place for me to post this, but I can't find your email. Looks like you've got this figured out and very few people know about Google APIs. Could you please take a look at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371503/gdata-google-finance-api-having-trouble and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've looked at your solutions here and I still cant get it.

Comment: @MarkLyons, do you have an image on the page which is loading from the same domain as your page (as per my last bullet point)?

Comment: @MarkLyons, it makes a difference. It's a Google requirement.

Comment: I'll give it another try. I'm going to assume its a problem with something else. Did you check my question page?

Comment: That's not fixing it :( Can you see anything else that might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@James Hill:
Yes, it's working when run from a server. There is a small bug though:-
When you run it for the first time, it doesn't return contacts. Try calling 'logMeOut()' just before you invoke 'initFunc()'. It will just go to the 'Grant Access' page and come back but not display any contacts. Please fix that :)

Comment: @haltTime, See above edit. Also, This should have been a comment, not an additional answer...

Comment: @James: The code is working fine in Firefox 4.0.1 but not with Chrome. A demo is up at http://researchweb.iiit.ac.in/~abhinav_mehta/google-contacts/test.html -- Chrome says "Insecure script has been blocked - Load Anyway(not recommended)". Even after allowing it to load script, it doesn't show Gmail contacts on the page.

Comment: Be sure to post when you overcome the problem.